# I can't insert a jsFiddle link in my answer

Tags: discussion, answers, link-only-answers

I can't insert a jsFiddle link in my answer, I even used 4 space before my link and the snippet code but always I get error

[image]

This my question posted:

```
Yes you can do it, You will find my solution in Jsfiddle in this below [link][1]
```

if some one can help me to inset this link ?

Comment: Read the error. It tells you how to fix the issue: Add _your code_ to the answer itself. Answers should be self-sufficient and users should not have to go to another site to see the code that will help solve their issue. Plus, if the link ever breaks, your answer will become useless if the code is not in it. It's in your best interest to make sure your answers are self-sufficient, so you don't get downvotes 1) down the road when the links break and 2) from users who want to get rid of answers that will become useless when links break.

Comment: I have read the error message and I applied all the recommendation asking but still does not work, maybe there are special methods or a problem in the WYSIWYG

Comment: You didn't add the code from the jsFiddle, you moved the link into a code block. That isn't sufficient to fix the problem. You'll need to include the actual HTML, JavaScript and CSS from the fiddle. Even more so, you should avoid answering VLQ questions to begin with.

Comment: @yellowantphil  My answer it's in the link, what I wanted to share

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So here's the *optimistic* scenario.  For an example, let's assume that you were able to post your answer intact.

Your answer would be downvoted since it's fairly low quality and *heavily* dependent on an outside resource; who is to say that jsFiddle is still up when someone wants to look at that answer years in the future?

You would then incur a lot of punishment for having your answer downvoted and (likely) deleted, which would count against you in an answer ban.

Now, the *reality* is that the system is actively preventing you from making this mistake by (at a minimum) making you post something more than a jsFiddle link.  If I were reading this answer, I wouldn't just want a code dump either; I'd want you to explain *why* this answer is correct and why it makes sense, with the code that you've written.

Also, Stack Snippets is a feature which is local to here which can take the place of jsFiddle; besides it being attached to Stack Overflow, it has the distinct advantage of adding your code to the answer as well.  To invoke it, look at the little image of two angle brackets when adding/editing an answer.