# Make jsFiddle without code block text more explicit

Tags: feature-request

Based on this existing meta question:

*[I can't insert a jsFiddle link in my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334990/i-cant-insert-a-jsfiddle-link-in-my-answer)*

Now consider the explanation that is given:

> **Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.** Please indent all code...

Why make it necessary to have to think about what that implies? Can't it just spell it out?

> Please add a copy of the code that was posted on jsfiddle.net to this answer as well.

Or a variation thereof if someone can phrase it even more bulletproof. The remainder of the text can be left as-is in my opinion.

---

**Makoto's** [alternative proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335013/424903) which I find much better:

> Your answer must contain more than a jsFiddle link. Please make
>   efforts to explain your code and approach, and leave the code you've
>   written in the answer itself.

Comment: It is very surprising to me that there are people formatting their JSFiddle links as code because they think that's what the system is telling them to do. It does explain some of the resistance I get when I leave "in the question itself" comments. I'm glad that particular cheat no longer works though. I'm assuming the down votes are from people who don't think the change will help.

Comment: Why not just disallow external links altogether for new users? Users with less than 10 reputation points currently cannot [post more than two hyperlinks at a time, either in a post or their user profile](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user). Notice that I specified external links, if users want to ask questions about other questions on Stack Overflow, or answers, they should be allowed to link to said content. Everything on Stack Overflow is cc-by-sa, so we can move the relevant content into the post without the world burning down, but JSFiddle does not have a compatible license.

Comment: @TinyGiant - I suspect what will happen is that people will start *explaining* how to reach their JSFiddle. Sort of like how people used to say where other YouTube videos were in their comments before they allowed links by just pasting the end, like ?v=iIMb3hGzWW8. *You can find my JSFiddle at /f5h3f9n0.*

Comment: @BSMP You can find the xkcd at [/810](https://xkcd.com/810/)

Comment: Just came across an answer in review where a JSFiddle link was posted as code, probably because of the ambiguity of the message: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39519980 (now deleted, 10K only).

Comment: I was fully expecting downvotes because I wasn't convinced my alternative text was any better ;) But let at least agree the current text is too open-ended

Answer (score 10):

Let's think about this for a moment...

Suppose we have a user (not necessarily the person in the other question, mind) that only wants to post code to their answers.  If they hit this message block, what would that message lead them to do?...Post their code in the answer.

Now, they've *done* what they were told to do, but the advice is hollow; they'll likely incur negative votes because *all they did was post code as an answer.*  They're now posting to Meta, upset because they followed the system-provided advice, but they're still getting punished for it and they want the punishment to stop.

The current message is very similar to enabling the scenario I describe; I'm no real fan of it.  But, we've got to display *some* kind of message.

Above all I'd prefer a world where we didn't *just* paste code as answers, but so long as we've got this one, I really don't want to enable it any clearer than what we've already got.

What if, instead, we changed the message to one that didn't advocate (directly or indirectly) that pasting a link and adding code was just fine?

> **Your answer must contain more than a jsFiddle link.**  Please make efforts to explain your code and approach, and leave the code you've written in the answer itself.

Comment: There will need to be something for when people do this in questions too. Can't think of anything good at the moment myself...

Comment: Oh yes, much better!